# how to delay an external page to load in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, i use this code to load an external page into a div. Now i want to build a little delay before loading. 
How can delay the loading of page3.html with 2 seconds?

```
$("#page3").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('calendar/page3.html');            
});
```

Comment: Did this (1st google hit) not work? https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: no, it seems not to work in combination with loading external page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#page3").click(function(){
    $('#result').delay(2000).queue(function(f) {
        $(this).load('/yourpage.html');
        f();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I try it on JSFiddle and works fine. Can you jsfiddle it... Any console errors?

Comment: please, can you show me the fiddle that i can see it works?

Comment: Ya, you're right. It looks like it was working, but its was the load time... Try the queue method [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/FBlade/jpnqoy2q/1/)